# ng-options values are equal to objects instead of value strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am building small Angular(1.5) app with two drop downs that are linked. Second one changes its options depending on the first dropdown menu. It all works well expect one small detail. Within HTML option tag, attribute value is equal to object:[some number] instead of the value itself. Displaying value ( the one between `<option>` and `</option>` tags) is displayed correctly.  Check screen shot. How do I make `value=""` equal to the same value as it is displayed between opening and closing tag?

[image]

HTML File:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="app-controller">
  <select id="brand"
    ng-model="input.selected_brand"
    ng-options="a for (a,b) in data"
  >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selection 1</option>
  </select>

  <select id="model"
    ng-model="input.selected_model"
    ng-options="a.model for a in input.selected_brand"
  >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selection 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS file:

```
var App = angular.module("App", [])
.controller('app-controller',function($scope,$http){
  // Fetch JSON data
  $http.get('data/data.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.data = res.data;
    $scope.selected_brand = $scope.data;
  });
});
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "BMW" : [
    {
      "model" : "M3 CRT"
    },
    {
      "model" : "M5"
    },
    {
      "model" : "M3 GTS"
    },
    {
      "model" : "M3 Coupe DCT"
    },
    {
      "model" : "M3 F80"
    },
    {
      "model" : "M6 Coupe"
    },
    {
      "model" : "M5/M6 CP"
    },
    {
      "model" : "X5/X6 M"
    },
    {
      "model" : "M6 Gran Coupe"
    },
    {
      "model" : "M3 E30"
    }
  ],
  "Mercedes" : [
    {
      "model" : "SL 65 AMG"
    },
    {
      "model" : "600 Pullman"
    },
    {
      "model" : "C111"
    },
    {
      "model" : "190E 2.5-16 EII"
    },
    {
      "model" : "SLR McLaren Stirling Moss"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Patent-Motorwagen"
    },
    {
      "model" : "500E"
    },
    {
      "model" : "CLK GTR"
    },
    {
      "model" : "300 SL"
    }
  ],
  "Lamborghini" : [
    {
      "model" : "Espada"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Jalpa"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Urraco"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Reventon"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Gallardo"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Sesto Elemento"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Diablo"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Countach"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Veneno"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Miura"
    }
  ],
  "Audi" : [
    {
      "model" : "RS2"
    },
    {
      "model" : "TT"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Le Mans"
    },
    {
      "model" : "R18 E-Tron"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Union Type D"
    },
    {
      "model" : "RS6 Avant"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Horch 26/65"
    },
    {
      "model" : "DKW Monza"
    },
    {
      "model" : "R8"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Quattro"
    }
  ],
  "Ford" : [
    {
      "model" : "Mustang Byllitt"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Boss 429"
    },
    {
      "model" : "SVT Cobra"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Fairlane Thunderbolt"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Focus RS"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Falcon 351"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Ford Mustang"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Cobra R"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Shelby GT350"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Ford GT"
    }
  ],
  "Honda" : [
    {
      "model" : "S200 CR"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Jackson Turbo"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Accord Coupe"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Civic Si"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Prelude VTEC"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Civic Mugen"
    }
  ],
  "Mazda" : [
    {
      "model" : "Mazda Carol"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Rotary Pickup"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Atenza"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Savanna"
    },
    {
      "model" : "RX-8"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Eunos Cosmo"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Autozam AZ-1"
    },
    {
      "model" : "Cosmo L10B"
    },
    {
      "model" : "MX-5 Miata"
    },
    {
      "model" : "RX-7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Reason why I go trough this is because I have

```
  $scope.submit = function(input){
    $scope.input_data = angular.copy(input);
    console.log($scope.input_data);
  }
```

Which needs correct values to work properly, in current state console.log output looks like this:

```
Object { selected_brand: Array[10], selected_model: Object }
```

Comment: angular sets the value with internal syntax so it can properly bind to model

Comment: @charlietfl but `$scope.input_data = angular.copy(input)` gets Array as first input value and Object as second input value instead of string values. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to do is:

```
    <select id="brand"
    ng-model="input.selected_brand"
    ng-options="a as a for (a,b) in data"
  >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selection 1</option>
  </select>

  <select id="model"
    ng-model="input.selected_model"
    ng-options="a.model as a.model for a in data[input.selected_brand]"
  >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selection 2</option>
  </select>
```

Also, you don't have to worry about the value within the generated code since angularjs use it internally to make some references. What really matters is the actual value passed to the model.

Comment: `   ng-options="a as b for (a,b) in data">` gives me alot of objects in my dropdown menu instead of values to select. Also the reason why I go trough  this is because I have `$scope.input_data = angular.copy(input)` which reads first input as an array and second input as an object. (I edited question check, bottom of the question).

Comment: Sorry. What you want: First select: a car Brand, second select: a car model. The angularjs's models should hold what exactly?

Comment: For example if you select BMW brand and M5 model, I need it to give me 2 strings "BMW" and "M5". However this code gives me Array and an Object.

Comment: Got it... You want a string containing the brand and another containing the model. I'm going to setup a plunkr

Comment: Yeah. The problem is the array one. The second one is object and I can get string easy from it. But this Array[10] holds no value that I can use. I am not sure where I went wrong with this code, I am only 2 days into Angular.

Comment: I just edited my answer if the fix. Nothing is necessary in the controller besides the $scope.data declaration.

Comment: This is now working very well and it also improved some small details too. I am grateful!